# Imprimir dados do DataGridView sem fundo escuro

Tags: c#, datagridview

Olá!
Tenho um código que imprime dados do `DataGridView`, porém, modifiquei as cores do mesmo. Com isso o código incorpora a cor do `DataGridView` à página de impressão. Gostaria que o código apenas imprimisse os dados da tabela, sem adicionar as cores do `DataGridView`. Utilizei para imprimir a tabela, um código chamado [DGVPrinter](http://codeproject.com/Articles/18042/Another-DataGridView-Printer).

```
private void btImprimirUsuarios_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            using (PrintDocument print = new PrintDocument())
                print.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
            DGVPrinter printer = new DGVPrinter();
            printer.TitleFont = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
            printer.Title = "LOGS DO SISTEMA - USUÁRIOS - SISTEMA DE MARCAÇÃO DE ÔNIBUS DA SAÚDE - MarcaBUS";
            printer.SubTitleFont = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
            printer.SubTitle = "Desenvolvido pela Divisão de Tecnologia da Informação - Prefeitura Municipal de João Monlevade";
            printer.SubTitleSpacing = 5;
            printer.SubTitleFormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.LineLimit | StringFormatFlags.NoClip;
            printer.PageNumbers = false;
            printer.PageNumberInHeader = false;
            printer.PorportionalColumns = true;
            printer.RowHeight = DGVPrinter.RowHeightSetting.CellHeight;
            printer.HeaderCellAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            printer.FooterFont = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
            printer.Footer = "Sistema MarcaBus - Copyright© 2020 Todos os Direitos Reservados";
            printer.FooterSpacing = 5;
            printer.DocName = "Logs de Cadastros, Exclusões e Alterações de Usuários - Marca Bus";
            printer.PrintPreviewDataGridView(dgvUsuarios);
}
```

Como fica:

[image: DataGridView]

Como preciso que fique:

[image: DataGridView]

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: essa variável é o que: `DGVPrinter`?

Comment: Eu utilizei sim, a `DGVPrinter` - @VirgilioNovic

Comment: o que é ??? `DGVPrinter`

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18042/Another-DataGridView-Printer

Comment: Version 1.2 - Finally (I believe!), fixed the string/column alignment problems. Also prints cell background colors properly, respecting the alternating rows style !!! ou seja, a cor vem do GridView e você precisa então mandar um GridView corretamente... OK!

Comment: antes de imprimir coloca a cor q vc quer, dps volte a cor normal